# Extracting Jdata

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to make a simple schedule plugin for a Joomla template, but I am having difficulties extracting the data I want from my SQL server. This is my first time using `JDatabase`, and I have tried different solutions for a while without getting a positive result.

What I want to do is to extract all the rows that contains the correct value in date. I'm getting it to show all entries for the fields I request, but my problem is when I want to get all the values for a specific date like the 17th of May.

```
protected function getListQuery()
{
        $db    = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select($db->quoteName(array('date', 'weekday' , 'start' , 'end' , 'instructor' , 'text' , 'ordering')));
        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__schedule_'));
        $query->where($db->quoteName('date') . " = " . $db->quote(2016-05-17));
        $query->order('ordering ASC');

        return $query;
}
```

Comment: `2016-05-17` is a string, therefore you need to replace `$db->quote(2016-05-17)` with `$db->quote('2016-05-17')`

Comment: Thank you, sometimes the most obvious things are the hardest to spot

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer and mark it as accepted, so others know it has been solved.